# Docker - Dont see mongoDB image after docker-compose build

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am doing my first steps with docker compose and made a docker-compose.yml file which contains:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  web:
    build: ./frontend
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
  api:
    build: ./backend
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    environment:
      DB_URL: mongodb://db/slip
  db:
    image: mongo:4.0-xenial
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - slip:/data/db

volumes:
  slip:
```

However after running `$ docker-compose build`
This is my result images in docker:

```
REPOSITORY   TAG                  IMAGE ID       CREATED              SIZE
slip_api    latest               445199e1e418   43 seconds ago       184MB
slip_web    latest               c1168ad560b8   About a minute ago   299MB
node         14.16.0-alpine3.13   50bfd284aa0d   10 months ago        117MB
```

I am not sure why I don't see the mongo:4.0-xenial image, and also not sure why I see the node:14.16.0-alpine3.13 which is a base (FROM) in docker file of the slip_api and slip_web and not an image by itself that I built.

Using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker-compose build` does literally that: it builds images. In order for an image to be built, the base image needs to present. That is the reason, why you are seeing the `node` image present.

You do not see the mongoDB image, because it is not built. Once you attempt to `docker-compose up` it will pull the latest version of `mongo:4.0-xenial`